# Where is Hiranyagarbha?

Tags: creation

The keshetra of the Anandaful ,  Beautiful Golden Womb - Golden Egg known as Hiranyagarbha the seed of all is located where ? Is it
Beyond Nirguna Brahman or is it within Sarguna Brahman?

Comment: Your question title is misleading and unclear.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer from the scriptures AFAIK but a valid question. I have understood what u meant to ask.

Comment: I understand that you are using Chicken and egg in a metaphorical way. Egg is hiranya garbha. Who is Chicken here? Your question seems unclear. Can you clarify what you mean? Did I understand it right?

Comment: Now ur question has changed to a new one :D

Comment: @Rickross ya it was put on hold as unclear. Do i delete the question or edit the question ? Which is better?

Comment: @Frank flag it for moderator attention. And mention that you have edited the question.

Comment: You don't have to delete.. But is this the question u originally wanted to ask? @FrankHestermann

Comment: When seed swells.and becomes a tree it transforms. You wont find seed anymore but it has become the tree itself

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi How very true but if you observe the bigger picture you realise that the seed has not only become the tree but also become  a multitude of seeds.

Comment: @FrankHestermann yes this is the view of many vedic statements and agamas

Comment: Golden Egg refers to this our material universe. It is not Brahman, and it is not Anandaful or "full of ananda or bliss" either. But World of Brahman is full of bliss or ananda.

Comment: If you are in search for bliss of ananda you can find it in the state of moksha in the spiritual world called Vaikuntha or World of Brahman.

Answer (score 7):

**Hiranyagarbha** literally means the Golden Womb or by extension - **One born from the Golden Womb** - which refers to Brahma's birth from the golden egg that became the Universe. The famous **[Hiranyagarbha Sukta](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10121.htm)** of the Rigveda states:

> 1. **IN the beginning rose Hiranyagarbha, born Only Lord of all created beings. He fixed and holdeth up this earth and heaven.** What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 2. Giver of vital breath, of power and vigour, he whose commandments all the Gods acknowledge - The Lord of death, whose shade is life immortal. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 3. Who by his grandeur hath become Sole Ruler of all the moving world that breathes and slumbers; **He who is Lord of men and Lord of cattle**. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 4. **His, through his might, are these snow-covered mountains, and men call sea and Rasā his possession:His arms are these, his are these heavenly regions.** What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 5. By him the heavens are strong and earth is steadfast, by him light's realm and sky-vault are supported:By him the regions in mid-air were measured. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 6. To him, supported by his help, two armies embattled look while trembling in their spirit, When over them the risen Sun is shining. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 7. What time the mighty waters came, **containing the universal germ (Hiranya-garbha), producing Agni, Thence sprang the Gods’ one spirit into being.** What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 8. He in his might surveyed the floods containing productive force and generating Worship. He is the God of gods, and none beside him. What God shall we adore with our oblation?
> 9. Never may he harm us who is **earth's Begetter,** nor he whose laws are sure, the **heavens' Creator,** He who brought forth the great and lucid waters. What God shall we adore with our oblation?

The above verses sort of confirm what we know about Hirayagarbha in the form of Brahma - he was born from the waters, he created the earth, mid-air and heavens, he is also the ruler of living beings as well as non-living structures like mountains and seas. The **[Devi Bhagwat Puran](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk08ch01.htm)** also reaffirms Brahma as Hiranyagarbha:

> The powerful Svâyambhuva Manu, the First, the husband of S'atarûpâ, the prosperous and the Ruler of all the Manvantaras worshipped the sinless Prajâpati Brahmâ, his Father with due devotion and satisfied Him when the Grandsire of the Lokas, the **Hiranyagarbha spoke to his son**:-- The excellent worship of the Devî should be done by you. By Her Grace, O Son, your work of creating worlds will be successful. Thus spoken by Brahmâ, the Bibhu Svâyambhuva Manu, the Virât incarnate, worshipped the World Mother with great austerities. And with his concentrated devotion, he satisfied the Devî Deves'î and began to chant hymns to Her, the First-born, the Mâyâ, the S'akti of all, and the Cause of all causes.

Therefore **Hiranyagarbha is an epithet of Brahma who resides in the Brahmaloka.**

Answer (score 6):

In Hindu scriptures Hiranyagarbha is actually associated with one the Trinities viz: Lord BrahmA.

Now, Lord BrahmA has many GAyatri Mantras dedicated to him. One such Mantra is the following:

> [image]
>
> Om vedAtmanAya vidmahe **hiranyagarbhAya** dhimahi tanno brahmA
>   prachodayAt ||

So, here Lord BrahmA is explicitly identified with Hiranyagarbha.

Thus, the answer to your current question is ["Brahmaloka"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmaloka), which is the abode of Lord BrahmA.

No, Hinranyagarbha is not beyond Nirguna Brahman. At the onset of creation Brahman manifests himself as Hiranyagarbha and pervades the creation. Other names for Hiranhyagarbha are MahAnAtmA, SutrAtmA etc.

Answer (score 0):

I quite dont agree with both the answers, as I feel they lack the deeper understanding of the concept of what is Hiranya gharba.
Quoting Ramana Maharshi,
"Just while rising from sleep and before seeing the objective world, there is a state of awareness which is your pure self". Here, he is telling what Hiranya gharba is.
It is essentially the Chittah without identity. Hence also the cause for all manifestations we see. It is infinite and eternal, so localizing it to Brahmaloka, or any other place is totally wrong. It is essentially all pervading and timeless.
It could also be said as the cause for all activities across (I mean all across the universe, from the tinest atomic actions to human actions to stars and galaxies - basically everything).